# Karma test fails in Firefox with strange error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I've got a very odd behavior with one of my tests.
It runs successfully in Chrome, but always fails in Firefox.
It tests a directive and error occurs in `beforeEach` block.

```
TypeError: menu is null (path/to/file.js:6)  //This points to a block of comments
process.on/global.onerror@/dir/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:5708 //This function throws every unhandled error
```

The directive itself work properly in Firefox. `beforeEach` compiles it and sets some properties on the scope. Strange as it may seem, all tests of the `describe` block report they have passed, but WebStorm reports that only 24 out of 28 `it`s are done.

Any ideas what the hack is going on?

Comment: could you please share your directive code and your testSpec code

Comment: About the `24 out of 28` error, sometimes Firefox doesn't complete the test suites if more than 2 Error occurs during the execution without being catch.